# how do I load data for second/more Time and put in one array- react callback / async / useEffect

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

at first in  onload or rendering component data will come and everything good.
this code write in else{} in useeffect

```
const [data1,setData1] = useState([]); // getlistingHome item..
    const vv =(data2)=>{
    for (let i in data2){
        
        setData1([...data1,data2[i]]); 
    }
}
useEffect(()=>{
        const setter =async()=>{

            if ( page_c != 1) //c
            {
                const second_data = await(getlistinghome(page_c)); //data that load for second time
                vv(second_data);//async function to loop in list of data
                
            }
            else {setData1(await(getlistinghome(page_c)))} //frist load
        }
        setter();},
[page_c])
```

vv() function isn't work properly it just add last object from second_data to data1(data1 is state that hold all data)

what can I do ?

Comment: There is no need to have the `for` loop there. Just do `setData1([...data1, ...data2]);`

Comment: Tnk you It work properly